# MariaDB fails to work after being idle for a period

Tags: java, tomcat7, mariadb

On my webapp, I often get the following exception:
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not send query: Last packet not finished
it usually happens after a long period of time the system is idle. 
A restart to the tomcat solves the issue temporarily.

I've recently moved to RHEL7 on my production server (running tomcat7 and mariaDB 5.5).
This error hadn't not happened on the old server (ran RHEL5 with mySQL).
I updated the java database drivers from mysql drivers that were used on the old server, to the latest stable mariadb connector: mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar.

Any ideas how to fix the problem or a workaround?

Here is the full log of this exception:

`Lexicon Message: Content.getData Error trying to excute: SELECT * FROM prefixes where prefix ='l'
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not send query: Last packet not finished
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.get(SQLExceptionMapper.java:136)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.throwException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:106)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MySQLStatement.java:264)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:288)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:338)
        at snaq.db.CachedStatement.execute(CachedStatement.java:339)
        at mila.lexicon.dbUtils.Connected.getData(Connected.java:257)
        at mila.lexicon.dbUtils.Prefixes.get(Prefixes.java:29)
        at mila.lexicon.analyse.Data.getPrefixes(Data.java:446)
        at mila.HMM.HMM2Morph.handlePrefixProperNameAnalysis(HMM2Morph.java:1196)
        at mila.HMM.HMM2Morph.parseXML(HMM2Morph.java:1791)
        at mila.HMM.HMM2Morph.process(HMM2Morph.java:2337)
        at org.apache.jsp.processAnalyzerXML_jsp._jspService(processAnalyzerXML_jsp.java:187)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1024)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.QueryException: Could not send query: Last packet not finished
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.executeQuery(MySQLProtocol.java:984)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:281)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Last packet not finished
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.packet.PacketOutputStream.startPacket(PacketOutputStream.java:38)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.packet.commands.StreamedQueryPacket.send(StreamedQueryPacket.java:76)
        at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.executeQuery(MySQLProtocol.java:982)
        ... 32 more`

Comment: Sounds like you connection pool is not sending keep-alive messages often enough

Comment: How did you end up solving this issue? We're running into the exact same problem when we migrated to a DPCP.

Comment: I dont remember exactly.  I either raised the timeout on the server or changed the timeout on the clients to be shorter than the timeout on the server. Currently the timeout in thr java app stands on 18000.

Comment: This is an issue of mariadb connector: https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/CONJ-68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have enough informations but I had the similar issue with mysql server. The problem was solved after changing timeout settings in `my.cnf`

```
wait_timeout        = 28800        
interactive_timeout = 28800
```

28800 secons - 8 hours

Restart your server to apply the changes

Comment: Even thought i added wait_timeout and interactive_timeout, i had the same problem. Is there any other solution.