# How should I handle an SQLNonTransientConnectionException?

Tags: java, service, server, mariadb, hikaricp

This is the error:

```
5760 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not read resultset: unexpected end of stream, read 0bytes from 4
5761 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.get(SQLExceptionMapper.java:136)
5762 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.throwException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:106)
5763 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MySQLStatement.java:264)
5764 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:288)
5765 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeUpdate(MySQLStatement.java:317)
5766 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(MySQLPreparedStatement.java:156)
5767 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementProxy.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementProxy.java:61)
5768 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.java)
5769 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at com.testserver.deviceapi.data.DataDAO.insertBootEvent(DataDAO.java:64)
5770 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at com.testserver.deviceapi.server.ServerRunnable.processJsonObject(ServerRunnable.java:198)
5771 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at com.testserver.deviceapi.server.ServerRunnable.run(ServerRunnable.java:93)
5772 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
5773 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.QueryException: Could not read resultset: unexpected end of stream, read 0bytes from 4
5774 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.getResult(MySQLProtocol.java:926)
5775 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.executeQuery(MySQLProtocol.java:991)
5776 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:281)
5777 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: ... 8 more
5778 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: Caused by: java.io.EOFException: unexpected end of stream, read 0bytes from 4
5779 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.packet.buffer.ReadUtil.readFully(ReadUtil.java:84)
5780 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.packet.buffer.ReadUtil.readFully(ReadUtil.java:92)
5781 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.packet.RawPacket.nextPacket(RawPacket.java:77)
5782 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.packet.SyncPacketFetcher.getRawPacket(SyncPacketFetcher.java:67)
5783 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.getResult(MySQLProtocol.java:894)
5784 feb 04 07:45:17 TestServer java[13777]: ... 10 more
```

The server is a java server, running as a service on CentOS. I've only implemented it as a service yesterday, and it's my first attempt to try do something like that. As of yesterday evening everything was OK. I've tested the server from the LAN and connected from outside the LAN without any issues, all data was processed and saved successfully.

Here's what the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLNonTransientConnectionException.html) has to say about `SQLNonTransientConnectionException`:

> The subclass of SQLException thrown for the SQLState class value '08',
>   or under vendor-specified conditions. This indicates that the
>   connection operation that failed will not succeed if the operation is
>   retried without the cause of the failure being corrected. Please
>   consult your driver vendor documentation for the vendor-specified
>   conditions for which this Exception may be thrown.

[SQL class value '08'](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.codes/src/tpc/db2z_sqlstatevalues.dita%23db2z_sqlstatevalues__code08?lang=en) means:

> ```
> Table 6. Class Code 08: Connection Exception
> SQLSTATE Value    Meaning
> 08001             The connection was unable to be established to the application server or other server.
> 08002             The connection already exists.
> 08003             The connection does not exist.
> 08004             The application server rejected establishment of the connection.
> ```

So I came in this morning and tried to save some data to the database with my test client when these errors occurred. After a couple of tries I ran the server on my local machine, the exact same version, and it worked without any issues whatsoever, successfully connected to the database on the main server and saved the same data from the same client without any problems.

Next I restarted the service on the main server. From that point on everything is back to normal, and I'm none the wiser as to what happened to cause the error.

Could it be something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755943/mariadb-fails-to-work-after-being-idle-for-a-period)? 
But that error message is `Last packet not finished` where mine is `Could not read resultset: unexpected end of stream, read 0bytes from 4`.

Have you guys any idea what this might be? 
How should I handle it? 
Since the error clearly states that the issue won't resolve itself on a retry I'm thinking I can catch the error and shut the server down. The service is set to restart straight away, so CentOS will restart it once it shuts itself down. 
Is this a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: Possibly check your database connection timeouts, and make sure that the pool maxLifetime is configured for 2 minutes or so shorter.

Comment: OK, I'll check that.